# Loading another WebPage and moving the Focus

Tags: javascript, html, focus

this is what I am trying to do:

I am loading another webpage(Facebook) into my own webpage, using window.open, and i wanted to move the focus of that page, to a specific object, like the password text field (using javascript). If it is necessary, i can always load the second page using another method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's impossible, you will not be able to do anything with that page. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately due to security reasons, you cannot do this without cooperation of Facebook.

[About Cross-Frame Scripting and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)